# Determining if a given Python module is part of the standard library

Tags: python, module, standard-library

How can I determine whether a Python module is part of the standard library?
In other words: is there a Python equivalent of perl's corelist utility?

I would use this to set my expectations on portability during development.
In case it's implementation dependent, I'm interested in CPython.

The best answer I found so far is this:

[Which parts of the python standard library are guaranteed to be available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334536/which-parts-of-the-python-standard-library-are-guaranteed-to-be-available)

That is to search for the module name on the index page of the Python Standard Library Documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/. However, this is less convenient than having a utility and also does not tell me anything about minimally required versions.

Comment: Note that some modules are only present if Python is compiled with certain settings, for example if you compile Python on a machine without sqlite headers installed the interpreter won't have sqlite support, even though the module is a part of the standard lib since Python 2.5. So it may be a little bit tricky in some corner cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using a setuptools install script (`setup.py`), you *test* for the required module, and update the installation dependencies list to add backports if needed.

For example, say you need the `collections.OrderedDict` class. The documentation states it was added in Python 2.7, but a [backport is available](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict) that works on Python 2.4 and up. In `setup.py` you test for the presence of the class in `collections`. If the import fails, add the backport to your requirements list:

```
from setuptools import setup

install_requires = []

try:
    from collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    install_requires.append('ordereddict')

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=install_requires
)
```

then in your code where you need `OrderedDict` use the same test:

```
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    # use backported version
    from ordereddict import OrderedDict
```

and rely on `pip` or `easy_install` or `zc.buildout` or other installation tools to fetch the extra library for you.

Many recent core library additions have backports available, including `json` (called `simplejson`), `argparse`, `sqlite3` (the `pysqlite` package, use `from pysqlite2 import dbapi as sqlite3` as a fallback).

You'll *still* have to read the documentation; the Python documentation is *excellent*, and for new modules, classes, methods, functions or arguments the documentation mentions explicitly in what Python version they were added.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation for the module.  You say you want a utility because reading the docs is inconvenient.  But you're coding against the module?  You should take a moment to read the docs in this case anyway, unless you are simply making a Frankenstein's monster by pasting together mysterious snippets you find online.

You won't be using dozens and dozens of modules, you can afford to spend a moment reading the docs. Also, generally, the docs do mention what version of Python introduced them.

The docs are good: use them.