# Why is Python saying modules are imported when they are not?

Tags: python

Python 3.6.5

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483269/20607842) as a guide, I attempted to see whether some modules, such as `math` were imported.

But Python tells me they are all imported when they are not.

```
>>> import sys
>>> 'math' in sys.modules
True
>>> 'math' not in sys.modules
False
>>> math.pi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
>>> import math
>>> 'math' in sys.modules
True
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are math.py and sys.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857355/where-are-math-py-and-sys-py)

Comment: If `math` is a builtin, why won't it work unless I import it?

Comment: Because even builtin modules need to be imported. That's how the language works

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Not necessarily. I don't have Python 3.6 available to test, but in Python 3.9 at least, `math` is *not* a built-in module like  (say)`os`.

Comment: "_But Python tells me they are all imported_" No, Python does not tell you that. `sys.modules` is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been **loaded** (not imported in the current scope). Also note this is only true for the interactive interpreter. If you run `python -c "import sys; print('math' in sys.modules)"`, you will see that it prints `False`.

Comment: PS: `math` is not a built-in, it's just part of the [Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html)

Comment: @chepner, even `os` is not a built-in module. AFAIK, there are no built-in modules at all. There all built-in [Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), [Constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html), [Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) and [Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

Comment: @wovano There *are* built-in modules. These modules are compiled into the interpreter. Try this: `import sys; print(sys.builtin_module_names)`. You'll see `math` there.

Comment: @S.B, interesting, didn't know that. Although the concept seems a bit different though. At least the built-in Functions, Constants, Types and Exceptions are part of the Python language and are always available. The built-in modules are interpreter-specific and are not readily available (they must be imported).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to explain this, let's define this function:

```py
def import_math():
    import math

import_math()
```

the above function will import the module math, but only in its local scope, anyone that tries to reference `math` outside of it will get a name error, because `math` is not defined in the global scope.

any module that is imported is saved into sys.modules so a call to check

```py
import_math()
print("math" in sys.modules)
```

will print True, because sys.modules caches any module that is loaded anywhere, whether or not it was available in the global scope, a very simple way to define `math` in the global scope would then to

```py
import_math()
math = sys.modules["math"]
```

which will convert it from being only in `sys.modules` to being in the global scope, this is just equivalent to

```py
import math
```

which defines a variable `math` in the global scope that points to the module `math`.

now if you want to see whether "math" exists in the global scope is to check if it is in the global scope directly.

```py
print("math" in globals())
print("math" in locals())
```

which will print false if "math" wasn't imported into the global or local scope and is therefore inaccessable.