# How to convert particilar format date to yyyy-mm-dd format in javascript

Tags: javascript

Tried to convert date format but not working.
my input is 23th Oct 2054 output shoud be like 2054-10-23. How to do it in javascript?
my code is not working.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var m = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2)
    month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2)
    day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th Dec 2059"];

var results=formatDate(dates);

console.log(results.join('\n'),+'\n');
```

output should be

```
2054-10-23  
2014-07-29  
2054-05-12 
2050-06-20 
2059-12-23
```

Comment: And after the "ver" fix, doubt you'll get desired results with `23th Oct 2054`

Comment: @GetSet: Not working

Comment: Someone commented on making "ver" to "var". And you did so. But unfortunately for some unknown reason, you also decided to pass in array of dates to your function that doesn't work on arrays.

Comment: @GetSet:How to get solution?

Comment: "DDth Mmm YYYY" is not a format that `new Date()` accepts, some reading tells me it needs to be a a string that is able to be understood by a `Date.parse()`, otherwise I believe you need a time library or manually parsing it yourself and re arrange it. `Date.parse("23th Oct 2054") is NaN`

Comment: @ajax333221: Someone did in different language but i do not know how to write in javascript..if you know pls help me:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309166/how-to-change-date-string-format-20th-oct-2052-2052-10-20

Comment: Your input date is stored in an array which you are submitting to your function, but your function is expecting a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dirty regex solution that does not use the Date object:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var newDates = date.map((item) => {
    var m = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var day = item.match(/\d+/)[0];
    day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day;
    var month = m.indexOf(item.match(/\s([A-Za-z]{3})\s/)[1]) + 1;
    month = month < 10 ? "0" + month : month;
    var year = item.match(/\d{4}$/)[0];
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  });
  return newDates;
}

var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th Dec 2059"];
console.log(formatDate(dates));
```

Comment: Output should be like 2054-10-23 that is yyyy-mm-dd format..and check in my question ..i am passing array as a input

Comment: pls check..i am passing dates as an array var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th Dec 2059"];
console.log(formatDate(dates));

Comment: In this case you need to map the function onto the array. I will edit again. Done.

Comment: Can u map inside a function

Comment: What do you mean by "map inside a function"? Do you want the function to receive an array rather than a single date?

Comment: Please check my question..without touching outside script can u do it? i mean do not touch these lines var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th Dec 2059"];

var results=formatDate(dates);

console.log(results.join('\n'),+'\n');

Comment: Getting undefined

Comment: month shoud be with 0 not without 0 like july 7 is wrong. 07 is correct..how to do it?

Comment: same for date also

Comment: date should be double digit not single digit..date not like this 2054-04-7  ..it should be 2054-04-07

Comment: Can u answer this question? https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-peyjqa

Comment: how to convert object to a function

Comment: Did you try asking here on SO?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are passing an array into your function when it is expecting a string. You are also getting an invalid date object because `Date` does not accept your format.

`Date` will accept an ISO Date (2054-10-23), a short date (10/23/2054), or a long date (Oct 23 2054). Your format is very close to the "long date" format.

By removing the "-th", "-nd" or "-st" from your dates, it becomes an accepted long date format which you can pass when initializing a new `Date`:

```js
new Date(date.replace(/th|nd|st/, ""));
```

Your function works as intended now (assuming you are passing in a string instead of an array).

Cleaned up example:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  const dateObj = new Date(date.replace(/th|nd|st/, ""));
  let year = dateObj.getFullYear();
  let month = dateObj.getMonth() + 1;
  let day = dateObj.getDate();

  if (month.length < 2) month = "0" + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = "0" + day;

  return [year, month, day].join("-");
}

var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th Dec 2059"];
dates.forEach(date => console.log(formatDate(date)));
```

I recommend using [date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) or [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) when working with dates. Formatting them becomes much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Uh, I just did it manually

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  [d,m,y]=date.split(' ');
  d=d.split('').filter(a=>!isNaN(a)).join('');
  return [y,m,d].join('-');
}

var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th Dec 2059"];

dates.forEach(a=>console.log(formatDate(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In one word, MOMENT! :)

If you can get rid of the -th, -rd on the day number, you can use this great library (which is extremely flexible and useful).
-> https://momentjs.com/

```js
var dates = ["23 Oct 2054", "29 Jul 2014", "12 May 2054", "20 Jun 2050", "23 Dec 2059"];

console.log(dates.map(date => moment(date, 'DD MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<div id='html'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're passing an array to a function that doesn't accept an array. Secondly you're passing an invalid date format to Date().

This doesn't use Date(). It just assumes the last 4 digits are the year, the first 1-2 digits are the day, and that the month is in the middle. Case insensitive and whole month is allowed in date format.

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var m = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];
  var month = String(m.indexOf(date.split(/[\s-]/)[1].slice(0, 3).toLowerCase())+1),
    day = date.split(/[^0-9]/)[0],
    year = date.slice(-4);
    
  if (month.length < 2)
    month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2)
    day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

;
for (var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th dec 2059"], i=0; i<dates.length; i++) {
    console.log(formatDate(dates[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for this.

```js
var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th Dec 2059"];
console.log(formatDate(dates));


function formatDate(date) {
  var mainArr = [];
   if(!Array.isArray(date)) {
      date = [date];
   }
   for(i=0;i<date.length;i++) {
        var dateVal = date[i];
        var dateValArr = dateVal.split(' ');
        var filterDateArr = [];
        for(j=0;j<dateValArr.length;j++) {
          var val = dateValArr[j]
          if(j==0) { 
            var val = dateValArr[j].replace(/\D/g, ""); 
          }
          filterDateArr.push(val);
        }
        var filterDate = filterDateArr.join(' ');
        var d = new Date(filterDate),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2) {
            month = '0' + month;
            }
        if (day.length < 2) {
            day = '0' + day;
            }
            mainArr.push([year, month, day].join('-'));
      }
   return mainArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing array to function and operating on single item, also invalid string is passed to Date object. Check out below code

```js
function formatDate(dates) {
var result=[]
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    [d,m,y]=dates[i].split(' ');
    day=d.slice(0,d.length-2)
    month = (months.indexOf(m)+1).toString();
    year = y;

    if (month.length < 2)
      month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2)
      day = '0' + day;
    result.push([year, month, day].join('-'));
}
return result;
}

var dates = ["23th Oct 2054", "29th Jul 2014", "12th May 2054", "20th Jun 2050", "23th Dec 2059"];
console.log(formatDate(dates));
```